# Anaconda not working in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda

I installed Anaconda 3 in "C:\Anaconda3" and manually added the paths "C:\Anaconda3\Scripts", "C:\Anaconda3" in the PATH variable. I installed VS Code through the Anaconda Navigator which also installed the Anaconda Extension Pack for VS Code. I created a simple .py file and wanted to run it.

EDIT (23/5/2019): https://stackoverflow.com/a/56023532/9724217
This is the answer. Solved. The current Anaconda3 package comes with conda version 4.6.11. You need to manually update it to 4.6.14. The issue then gets solved. VS Code can be opened normally or via the Anaconda Navigator. It's fine both ways.

Comment: Why are you attempting to activating the `(base)` environment when you already appear to be in the `(base)` environment?

Comment: @Anaksunaman I am getting the exact same error when I freshly open VS Code and press "Run Code" for the .py file. I have the Python extension and the Code Runner extension. I should perhaps give a clearer error report.

Comment: I dont think you want to add Anaconda to your path. Its says that on when you first install it right? I would just install it from navigator and not mess with your paths at all. VS code install directly from the navigators homepage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLVED.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56023532/9724217 
This is the answer. The current Anaconda3 package comes with conda version 4.6.11 as of May 2019. You need to manually update it to 4.6.14. The issue then gets solved. VS Code can be opened normally or via the Anaconda Navigator. It's fine both ways.